# WARNING: lib not found: Qt5WebKitd.dll, Qt5Cored.dll pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyinstaller

I'm compiling a python script to .exe. But the output return some sort of missing lib. I tried to change the path using --path to the python qt/bin but same error. I tried console based, windowed, onefile even everything in pyinstaller. But same problem. When I run the script using python It work properly.

**Screenshot of Working Python script when I run it using Python**
[image]

**Screenshot When I run it from the compiled .exe**
[image]

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow,QApplication,QLineEdit,QPushButton,QTabWidget,QVBoxLayout,QWidget
from PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets import *
app=QApplication(sys.argv)
tabs=QTabWidget()
tabs.resize(400,300)
mainWindow=QMainWindow()
widget=QWidget()
mainWindow=QMainWindow()
mainWindow.setWindowTitle("Sprotechs")
web=QWebView()
web.load(QUrl("https://google.com"))

verticalLayout=QVBoxLayout()
verticalLayout.addWidget(web)

widget.setLayout(verticalLayout)
mainWindow.setCentralWidget(widget)
mainWindow.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Error Output**

```
21734 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries 23408 WARNING: lib not found: Qt53DLogic.dll dependency of C:\users\shop 129 c\a ppdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\qml\QtWebKit \qtquickscene3dplugin.dll 23445 WARNING: lib not found: Qt53DInput.dll dependency of C:\users\shop 129 c\a ppdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\qml\QtWebKit \qtquickscene3dplugin.dll 23491 WARNING: lib not found: Qt53DRender.dll dependency of C:\users\shop 129 c\ appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\qml\QtWebKi t\qtquickscene3dplugin.dll 23520 WARNING: lib not found: Qt53DCore.dll dependency of C:\users\shop 129 c\ap pdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\qml\QtWebKit\ qtquickscene3dplugin.dll 27549 WARNING: lib not found: Qt53DQuickScene2D.dll dependency of C:\users\shop 129 c\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\qml\Q tQuick\Scene2D\qtquickscene2dplugin.dll 27608 WARNING: lib not found: Qt53DRender.dll dependency of C:\users\shop 129 c\ appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\qml\QtQuick \Scene2D\qtquickscene2dplugin.dll 27653 WARNING: lib not found: Qt53DCore.dll dependency of C:\users\shop 129 c\ap pdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\qml\QtQuick\S cene2D\qtquickscene2dplugin.dll 29883 WARNING: lib not found: Qt5Qmld.dll dependency of C:\users\shop 129 c\appd ata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\qml\QtWebKit\ex perimental\qmlwebkitexperimentalplugind.dll 29914 WARNING: lib not found: Qt5Cored.dll dependency of C:\users\shop 129 c\app data\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\qml\QtWebKit\e xperimental\qmlwebkitexperimentalplugind.dll 29948 WARNING: lib not found: Qt5WebKitd.dll dependency of C:\users\shop 129 c\a ppdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\qml\QtWebKit \experimental\qmlwebkitexperimentalplugind.dll 29980 WARNING: lib not found: ucrtbased.dll dependency of C:\users\shop 129 c\ap pdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\qml\QtWebKit\ experimental\qmlwebkitexperimentalplugind.dll 30010 WARNING: lib not found: VCRUNTIME140D.dll dependency of C:\users\shop 129 c\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\qml\QtWeb Kit\experimental\qmlwebkitexperimentalplugind.dll 30041 WARNING: lib not found: Qt5Quickd.dll dependency of C:\users\shop 129 c\ap pdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\qml\QtWebKit\ experimental\qmlwebkitexperimentalplugind.dll 30320 WARNING: lib not found: Qt5Qmld.dll dependency of C:\users\shop 129 c\appd ata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\qml\QtWebKit\qm lwebkitplugind.dll 30347 WARNING: lib not found: Qt5Cored.dll dependency of C:\users\shop 129 c\app data\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\qml\QtWebKit\q mlwebkitplugind.dll 30378 WARNING: lib not found: Qt5WebKitd.dll dependency of C:\users\shop 129 c\a ppdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\qml\QtWebKit \qmlwebkitplugind.dll 30407 WARNING: lib not found: Qt5Networkd.dll dependency of C:\users\shop 129 c\ appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\qml\QtWebKi t\qmlwebkitplugind.dll 30435 WARNING: lib not found: ucrtbased.dll dependency of C:\users\shop 129 c\ap pdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\qml\QtWebKit\ qmlwebkitplugind.dll 30463 WARNING: lib not found: VCRUNTIME140D.dll dependency of C:\users\shop 129 c\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\qml\QtWeb Kit\qmlwebkitplugind.dll 30490 WARNING: lib not found: Qt5Quickd.dll dependency of C:\users\shop 129 c\ap pdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\qml\QtWebKit\ qmlwebkitplugind.dll 30707 WARNING: lib not found: Qt53DLogic.dll dependency of C:\users\shop 129 c\a ppdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\qml\QtQuick\ Scene3D\qtquickscene3dplugin.dll 30744 WARNING: lib not found: Qt53DInput.dll dependency of C:\users\shop 129 c\a ppdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\qml\QtQuick\ Scene3D\qtquickscene3dplugin.dll 30783 WARNING: lib not found: Qt53DAnimation.dll dependency of C:\users\shop 129 c\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\qml\QtQu ick\Scene3D\qtquickscene3dplugin.dll 30813 WARNING: lib not found: Qt53DRender.dll dependency of C:\users\shop 129 c\ appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\qml\QtQuick \Scene3D\qtquickscene3dplugin.dll 30843 WARNING: lib not found: Qt53DCore.dll dependency of C:\users\shop 129 c\ap pdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\qml\QtQuick\S cene3D\qtquickscene3dplugin.dll 31251 WARNING: lib not found: Qt5MultimediaQuick_p.dll dependency of C:\users\sh op 129 c\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\qm l\QtMultimedia\declarative_multimedia.dll 34212 INFO: Looking for eggs 34212 INFO: Using Python library c:\users\shop 129 c\appdata\local\programs\pyth on\python37-32\python37.dll
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried making a [python virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html), then installing all your needed packages and using pyinstaller? this may work and even output executable is very slimmer.

Comment: Yes I already made Python virtual environment but still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add to your environment PATH variable the path to your DLL. As it seems the pyinstaller is unable to find this dll when it is searching for all the dependencies that you have, hence at runtime when trying to start your application it is unable to.

In some cases it might simply be an error of pyinstaller so one needs to add manually the dll by using `--add-data` option: https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html (for more details)

One basic way to test that everything works well is that in the _MEIxxxxxx temporary folder created to manually add the dll and to start again the exe.